# You should use 'mysqli..' comment argument

Tags: discussion

It's not the first time... It has recurring for almost every MySQL question where the asker posting mysql query with `mysql_*` not `mysqli_*` as happening in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371124/simple-mysql-code-not-inserting-data-into-database). 
My question is, is this really effective? Well, we were all a newbie at one point and there will be a time where we will change or move from that `mysql_*` even without people saying so. And the usage of `mysql_*` is not dangerous as the asker might be someone who is learning from an outdated source, meaning using `mysql_*` would help them understanding the code much faster.
Example:

> Bobby learns MySQL from certain site (http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsyntax.php). 
> Bobby, who knows nothing about PHP, uses `mysql_*` function as it was written on the webpage.

Now, what if you, as Bobby, are asked to learn with MySQLi? That would means you have to convert each query into `mysqli_*` (Yes, I know... It's just a matter of adding *i* ). But then the code can be very messy as there can be some parts which Bobby uses `mysql` and `mysqli`.
So far, my teaching techniques are let the student uses `mysql` until they are *ready* enough to know what `mysql_*` stands for and then let them know (which some of them knows by themself), that they can use `PDO`, `mysqli`, and *stuffs*

Comment: The user is handling a sharp knife and cutting towards himself. Nothing has to go wrong right now, but at some point it might. He is of course free to do so and can follow any advice to keep doing so, but a little instruction to turn the knife around and cut away from the body might go a long way.

Comment: It's the same as when I see someone using archaic HTML elements like `center` and `frameset`...it usually doesn't prevent me from answering, but I'd be doing them a disservice if I didn't throw up a big red flag. As active SO users, we see such advice all the time, but you'd be surprised how many people are unfamiliar with best practices.

Comment: @TimMedora Don't forget the `font` tag :P

Comment: I believe transitioning from `mysql` to `mysqli` is just an inch move, which is very trivial, and IMO letting them learn on their _php for starters_ language would be more effective rather than pushing them with something that they will ask if they just start, like 'What is the difference between mysql and mysqli?'. I'd be best to let them learn `mysql` and then in the time, they will learn what is `mysqli` and why they should use them, by themselves, which _IMO_ is more effective rather than getting told again then he forgot and getting told again.

Comment: @WillyPt: The point isn't just to *move*, it's to remove the risk of SQL injection and learn how to query properly. Check my answer, I've explained it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is more effective then you might think. Even I got to know about PDO from one of those comments. Which is one of the reason that I'm constantly posting those comments. :P

It is a good idea to let the students learn from any source they prefer but not all sources are up-to-date and hence, we can and should inform them about good practices.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try giving out the spirit on _giving out good pratices_

Answer (score 10):

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

```
[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).
```

As the *author* of said comment, let me share my insight with you.

### It is effective

I've been getting some really good feedback, where I see the same people turning up later with PDO in their code, and sometimes asking about how to move from one to the other. Besides, if I helped just one user, it's all worth it in my eyes.

### `mysql_*` *is* dangerous

More than you think, it's easier for a noob to learn SQL injection prone code on `mysql_*` than it is to learn prepared statements on mysqli or PDO, we're showing them the other side. And the sooner the better.

### No one asked you to actively move

Read the comment, *Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in **new code***. We don't ask you to move your current code, that would indeed be messy and not helpful, but *from now on*, we want you to try to use a better library.

### We're seeking to improve

We were getting feedback from the regulars and mods that the comment is annoying, and [we're always trying to improve it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171933/how-should-we-handle-ext-mysql-deprecation-in-php-questions-older-included/171963#171963). If you have some alternative phrasing, feel free to start a meta post on it, or ping me in the PHP chat.

Comment: I always wanted to ask, why switch from bit.ly to j.mp?

Comment: @hjpotter92: There was a time where the comment *just barely* fit into the 600 character limit, so we had to shorten it in any way possible. j.mp is shorter than bit.ly by two characters, and that was significant given all the links we have :)

Comment: hmm, I created a smaller text using [this app](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) (^_^)